# ASKING: Facebook Get Profile Picture....Need Answer

Tags: facebook, profile, image

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'src/facebook.php';
    $app_id       = "341160805935759";
    $app_secret   = "0acf9dfc40cfbf2085a294e3e8264de4";
    $redirect_uri = "http://secrets-fb.info/thisisit/main.php";
    $facebook     = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));
    $user         = $facebook->getUser();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    $coded = $_REQUEST['code'];

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $name         = "" . $user_profile['name'] . "";
    $fbid         = "" . $user_profile['id'] . "";
    $birthday     = "" . $user_profile['birthday'] . "";

    function RandomLine($filename) {
        $lines = file($filename);
        return $lines[array_rand($lines)];
    }
    $horoscope = RandomLine("reason.txt");

    $canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg("kill.jpg");
    // background image file $black = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 0, 0, 0 ); 
    // The second colour - to be used for the text 
    $font   = "arial.ttf";
    // Path to the font you are going to use $fontsize = 24;              
    // font size

    imagettftext($canvas, 21, -1, 248, 205, $black, $font, $name);
    // User name imagettftext( $canvas, 21, -1, 255, 329, $black, $font,$horoscope ); 
    //horoscope imagettftext( $canvas, 21, -1, 255, 329, $black, $font, $birthday );


    imagejpeg($canvas, "img/" . $fbid . ".jpg", 50);

    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); //Create an album
    $album_details = array('message' => 'Daily Horoscope','name' => 'Daily Horoscope'); 
?>
```

---

I have this code above and it creates an album then post the image into
 user with the user's name and the horoscope detail i created in a text
 file. I can get the name of the user but i want to get the users
 PROFILE PICTURE also.  Supposed this is the result. Can somebody help
 me please...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With GraphAPI, you can **always** get profile picture in facebook with this link:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=$access_token
```

Answer (score 1):

Profile picture is publicly available and you don’t need PHP SDK or an access token to retrieve them.

The below mentioned link can be used to get the profile picture of a user.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/picture?type=large
```

Just use the below code to display the profile pic.

```
echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?type=large' />";
```